# access just one return value from function with multiple return values

Tags: python, generator, return-value, xlsxwriter

I am having trouble figuring out how I would access a value returned from a function where I am returning multiple values. I have a dictionary object that contains a tuple for the values like this.

```
import random

payments = {'12345678121365489': ('11', '2022', '666'),
            '5136982546823120': ('03', '2021', '523')}

def pick_card_combo():
    rand_dict, info = random.choice(list(practice_dict.items()))
    return(rand_dict, info)
```

Of course, I can index the "info" tuple and pick out certain elements but I was wondering how I could get each individual index for my generator expression in this function here.

```
def create_accounts(accs_gend):
    my_gen = ([first_name(), last_name(), country, pick_card_combo()
               <rand_dict>, <info[0]>, <info[1]>, <info[2]>] for i in range(accs_gend))
    account = tuple(my_gen)
    print(account)
```

I have different items in that dictionary so I would like for the various items to be used with the different tuples I generate and not just one item. Is there a way to access each respective return value here why calling this function each time a new element is generated?

I prefer to keep my generator objects inside the tuple as is too since that is the format which xlsxwriter requires it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want, but perhaps `my_gen = ([..., *pick_card_combo(), ...] for i in range(accs_gend)])`? (In Python 3, anyway.)

Comment: @chepner ... i think his info is still nested in its own sublist but thats sort of the avenue I was thiinking as well `a,b = pick_card_combo();my_gen = ([first_name(), last_name(), country,]+ [a,] + b)`

Comment: Can you give us a more complete example? Your `pick_card_combo` function is just a `NameError`,  and I can't tell what your `my_gen` is supposed to be doing. If you can't explain what you want it to do in English, can you just write it out as an explicit, verbose list statement?

Comment: I want to populate my_gen with the key(rand_dict), and each of the separate elements in the info tuple. Those 4 "attributes" will be there own separate elements in the list generated in my_gen. If I were to put pick_card_combo() in the list contained in my_gen, then it would add something like this to the list, ('12345678121365489', ('11', '2022', '666')). I would rather have '12345678121365489', '11', 2022', '666' appended as separate elements to the list.

Comment: @JoranBeasley actually. I edit what I just said. it's not quite what I need but I think it's a start. thanks

Answer (score 1):

break it down more

```
def create_account():
    """ create one single account """
    rand_dict, info = pick_card_combo()
    return ([first_name(), last_name(), country,]+ [rand_dict,] + info )

def create_accounts(accs_gend):
    """ Create some number of random accounts """
    for i in range(accs_gend):
        yield create_account() # by using yield this is a "generator" 

five_random_accounts = tuple(create_accounts(5)) # calling tuple will evaluate the generator and create a tuple of all the elements
```